# Change kernel to another version of python instead of system Python in Mac OSX

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I've already installed a Python via HomeBrew as you can see below:

```
J-MBP:runtime my$ ll `which python`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 my  admin  34 Mar 31 14:20 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/python
J-MBP:runtime my$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)]'
```

However, when I run `jupyter notebook` and double-check on the python version, it still use the old version pre-installed on the system.

```
import sys
sys.version

Out[3]:  '2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]'
```

I'm wondering how to change the python to the newly-installed one in Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ipython kernel install`, check current kernel path. `cd` to it and then `vim kernel.json`.

```
{
 "display_name": "Python 2",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}
```

Change **argv** argument to the newly-installed python path will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can type `which jupiter` and edit the file. I guess that the previous version that was installed from homebrew is hardcoded in that file's shebang line to the path that `which python` returns

Comment: Partially you're right, the python path is harcoded in the first line of `jupyter` file. But there's no use after I switch it to my newly-installed python and restart again.